# Having list separated into bins automatically for Histogram plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a list of numbers as Histogram with Matplot, with x axis showing the bins and the y axis showing how many values each bin contains (not the sum of the numbers). My goal is to have the intervals of numbers included in each bin generated automatically, based on the data in the list.

For example, if this the list: [1,3,8,9,9,4,20,3,10,24,80,2,45,2,100,25], then I'd imagine that it would make sense to have 4 bins, like 1-10, 10-20,20-50, 50+. For example. If the list looks different, with a wider range of numbers, maybe 6 bins are better, and maybe the intervals of numbers in each bin would be much bigger.

How could I do that? I suspect that numpy or Pandas might be do that, but I am a beginner in the field of data visualization, so I haven't been able to figure it out myself.

Here is the very primitive code that I currently use for manual binning (and then I hand this to Matplot). I know I can make it shorter with better Python code, but I suspect that binning manually like that is not the best approach anyway.

```
# example values, list with time stamps in minutes
list_with_minutes =  [1,3,8,9,9,4,20,3,10,24,80,2,45,2,100,25]


bin1 = 0
bin2 = 0
bin3 = 0
bin4 = 0
bin5 = 0
bin6 = 0
bin7 = 0

for value in list_with_minutes:
    if value <= 5:
        bin1 += 1
    if value >= 6 and value <= 10:
        bin2 += 1
    if value >= 11 and value <= 30:
        bin3 += 1
    if value >= 31 and value <= 60:
        bin4 += 1
    if value >= 61 and value <= 120:
        bin5 += 1
    if value >= 121 and value <= 240:
        bin6 += 1
    if value >= 241:
        bin7 += 1

minute_bins = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
number_of_posts_list = [bin1,bin2,bin3,bin4,bin5,bin6,bin7]
```

Thanks.

Edit, as this question was identified as a possible dublicate: My question is not "how do Histograms with numpy work generally", but how to bin a list of numbers in some sort of automated manner depending on the range, character and quantity of numbers.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @MrGrj I am obtaining data from the API of a new service about when a certain item hit the front page. So the list I am talking about is a list of "minutes". Looking at the distribution, the majority of the values in the list are in the range of 5 to 200 (minutes).

Comment: @TomWyllie I saw that one before actually but I didn't manage to extract the information I needed, as this generally explains Histogram with numpy, but not my specific problem.

Comment: As long as you don't name the criterion by which you want to chose the number of bins, there is nothing we can do for you here.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but I added some code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are looking to implement your own binning with arbitrarily spaced bin boundaries. If so something like this should help you;

```
from collections import defaultdict

list_with_minutes = [1, 3, 8, 9, 9, 4, 20, 3, 10, 24, 80, 2, 45, 2, 100, 25]
bin_boundaries = [(0, 10),
                  (10, 20),
                  (20, 50),
                  (50, max(list_with_minutes))]
bin_counts = defaultdict(int)

for value in list_with_minutes:
    for low, high in bin_boundaries:
        if low < value <= high:
            bin_counts[(low, high)] += 1

print(bin_counts)
# defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {(50, 100): 2, (20, 50): 3, (0, 10): 10, (10, 20): 1})
print(bin_counts[(0, 10)])              # 10
print(bin_counts[bin_boundaries[2]])    # 3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort, that looks helpful for sure. I'll try to figure out how exactly it works and use it!